# ArrayOutOfRangeException when selecting a cell from DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am trying to get the primary key from a row in a DataGridView so that when a user double-clicks on any cell of the record, the value of the first cell which contains the key is stored in a variable "Key"
I have used the follwing code for this purpose.

```
Key= DGV1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value
```

The table contains columns like Key,First Name, Last Name and so on.

But when i double-click on the record i get the given exception saying that the index is negative or out-of-bounds.

Comment: Can you post more code? Where do you use the code above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double clicking doesn't select the row, so `SelectedRows` doesn't contain anything and `SelectedRows(0)` gives you the error.

If you want to handle double clicking on the cells, you can use the `CellDoubleClick` event of the datagridview. You can then use this code:

```
Private Sub DGV1_CellDoubleClick(sender as Object, e as DataGridViewCellEventArgs) _ 
 Handles DataGridView1.CellDoubleClick

    Key= DGV1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value

End Sub
```